# Start the Weeknum on Sunday as the first day of the week

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, strptime

The last day of 2017 (2017-12-31) falls on Sunday, meaning last week of the year only contains 1 day if I consider Sunday as the start day of my week. Now, I would like 2016-01-01 to 2016-01-07, to be associated with week 53, and start week 1 on 2016-01-03, which falls on Sunday.

I have the following data frame structure:

```
require(lubridate)
range <- seq(as.Date('2017-12-26'), by = 1, len = 10)
df <- data.frame(range)
ddf$WKN <- as.integer(format(df$range + 1, '%V'))
df$weekday <- weekdays(df$range)
df$weeknum <- wday(df$range)
```

This would give me this:

```
df:
range      WKN   weekday   weeknum
2017-12-26  52   Tuesday       3
2017-12-27  52 Wednesday       4
2017-12-28  52  Thursday       5
2017-12-29  52    Friday       7
2017-12-30  52  Saturday       7
2017-12-31  01    Sunday       1
2018-01-01  01    Monday       2
2018-01-02  01   Tuesday       3
2018-01-03  01 Wednesday       4
2018-01-04  01  Thursday       5
```

What I would like to have is:

```
df:
range      WKN   weekday   weeknum
2017-12-26  52   Tuesday       3
2017-12-27  52 Wednesday       4
2017-12-28  52  Thursday       5
2017-12-29  52    Friday       7
2017-12-30  52  Saturday       7
2017-12-31  53    Sunday       1
2018-01-01  53    Monday       2
2018-01-02  53   Tuesday       3
2018-01-03  53 Wednesday       4
2018-01-04  53  Thursday       5
.
.
2018-01-07  01    Sunday       1
```

Can anyone point me in a right direction?
@alistaire had provided solution here [Start first day of week of the year on Sunday and end last day of week of the year on Saturday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580450/start-first-day-of-week-of-the-year-on-sunday-and-end-last-day-of-week-of-the-ye) But I did not foresee this blip here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
Little Adjustments to this should serve my purpose!

```
df$WKN <- as.integer(format(df$range, '%U'))
```